# Trying to download rweibo library

Tags: r, weibo

I am trying to download the rweibo package from github thus:

```
devtools::install_github("sjhfx/Rweibo")
```

However, I am encountering a problem with the 'digest' package:

```
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error: Failed to install 'Rweibo' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’
```

I can't find a library called 'digest'. Also not sure if work is still ongoing on the rweibo package? since I don't hear about it on any blogs. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `installed.packages()[row.names(installed.packages()) == 'digest',]; remove.packages('digest')` and restart R

Comment: if the solution from above doesn't work, find the library directory, by running  `.libPaths() ` from the console. Go to the directory and delete `digest` folder manually. Repeat the installation.

Comment: Now I get * installing *source* package 'Rweibo' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'RCurl' was built under R version 4.0.5
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'Rweibo'

Comment: 3.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status